# How to keep gps at full power while device sleeps

Tags: iphone, swift, gps, cllocationmanager, sleep

My app needs to record (as precisely as possible) the user's location and movement over time. If I let the device sleep, the GPS accuracy seems to be automatically reduced. I can stop it from sleeping but obviously that is a further drain on the battery. I would like to allow the display to sleep, but maintain the max accuracy for the locationmanager. I have Location updates ticked in the Background Modes section. My code looks like this ...

```
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 1
    locationManager.activityType = .Fitness
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

I would really like to remove that last line, but all the testing I have done on a 4s suggests that as soon as the device sleeps it loses accuracy.

Comment: Could you please define the "location manager loses accuracy"? How exactly you define the accuracy here - is it horizontal accuracy for reported locations, distance filter, something else?

Comment: Yes, thanks for responding. I am measuring the horizontal accuracy (.horizontalAccuracy).

Comment: Can you tell how does .horizontalAccuracy change when going from foreground to background and finally to suspended mode? Can you post sample readings - I am interested in just three vars: horizontalAccuracy, speed and timestamp.

Comment: I have changed my app to 9.0 and used your answer to solve the problem. It works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is iOS 9 you also need this line:

locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;

By default this var is set to false, and that means iOS will not deliver location updates to a suspended app.

Comment: I was aiming for iOS 8. Do you happen to know if there is a way to do it using that version?

Comment: The allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates variable just allows to override new battery preserving behavior introduced by iOS9 and to revert to iOS8 mode of operations.